# MVC WebGrid setting up column value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, webgrid

Was looking everywhere but couldn't find an answer. I have a webgrid which displays data from an IEnumerable. I do not want to create a view model especially for the purpose of the grid, so while creating columns, I use related properties. Like so:

```
grid.Column(format: @<text>
                    @item.User.FullName
                    </text>,
            header: "User"),
```

That's for many to one relationship, and it works fine. I wanted to use similar trick with many to many like so:

```
grid.Column(format: @<text>
                    @item.Companies.FirstOrDefault().Title
                    </text>,
            header: "Company"),
```

But got an error  saying that

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<ActivityLog.Domain.Entities.Company>' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault'
```

Is than any other way I can source this value to use it in the webgrid?

Or should I:

opt 1) use some other presentation helper, or alternatively build an html table in foreach loop

opt 2) create view model to accommodate all properties needed for the WebGrid

Which one would be more appropriate do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added

```
@using System.Linq;
```

at the top of your cshtml file.

Comment: It has been added, I use the same way to access data in the foreach loop and everything works fine

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Question - http://stackoverflow.com/q/24545789/2943718?sem=2. Did you get a solution to this ?